# Я начал писать Telegram бота, но возникла небольшая проблема

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Мне надо проверять тот ли ID у чата при получении сообщения, но

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Вы писали метод getChatId()?

Comment: добавьте символ L после числа, и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию все числовые значения `java` рассматривает как `int`, ваше же указанное значение превышает `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, на это компилятор и ругается.
Но это значение помещается в `long` (собственно, `getChatId` как раз и возвращает `Long`), соответственно вам нужно явно указать что число имеет тип `long`, сделать это можно добавил `L` в конце числа, вот так: `-1001305998091L`.

В конце числа можно писать как строчную `l`, так и заглавную, но хорошим тоном считается писать именно заглавную `L`, так как строчную легко спутать с цифрой `1`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!